# Javascript comparison not working for 2 digit integers

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I am trying to find the largest number entered so far. This javascript runs good for one digit numbers. But doesn't work properly when a two digit number is entered.The largest value continues to be the largest one digit number.
I wonder why this is happening.Please help me out. Thanx in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
var number ;
var largest  ;
largest = 0;



while(counter!=10)
{


    number = window.prompt("Please enter a number");


    if(number>largest)
    {

        largest = number;


    }
    document.write(number+"  "+largest+"</br>");
    counter++;

}
```

This code

Answer (score 4):

Just use parseInt for the value coming from prompt. It will work as expected.

Like

```
number = parseInt(window.prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
```

[**see a demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7me0sj8n/1/)

Comment: hahaha same answer at the same time! :), yours include the radix, that's a good practice +1

Comment: and therefore worth a +1

Comment: @Diego : hey.. no problems brother. For me SO fiddle is not working. I cant get the insert into post to work. :(

Comment: @mithunsatheesh But Why comparison is working on single digit ??

Answer (score 3):

`window.prompt` is going to return a string. You need to convert it to number using `parseInt`.

Try this:

```
number = parseInt(window.prompt("Please enter a number"));
```

Comment: Thank you,,I had tried to parseInt the largest variable...this one works

Comment: Also see @mithunsatheesh answer, the second parameter of parseInt indicates the radix. It's optional, and 10 by default, but it's a good practice to include it.

Comment: @Diego it's optional, but you should _always_ include it, because on pre-ES5 browsers it'll treat numbers with a leading 0 as octal.  Even on ES5 it'll treat numbers with a leading `0x` as hex instead of an error.

Comment: @Diego: See [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Example:_Tricky_use_case) for Array.prototype.map(), it has a pretty scary example without using radix. :)

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the clarification, I thought that on new browsers the default was 10... it's good to know.

Comment: @mithunasatheesh yup scary example. map sends (value,index) to the function, so it's parsing '2' with base 2, '3' with base 3. It's more a mistake on the use of map, than an issue of parseInt

Comment: @Diego yes, on modern browsers if the radix is 0 or `undefined` then it's supposed to default to 10.  More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt